# java.security.cert.CertificateException: could not find trusted certificate

Tags: java

I am trying to invoke a secured web service.  But I am getting an exception saying,

```
Failed to create secure client socket: java.security.cert.CertificateException: com.tibco.security.AXSecurityException: could not find trusted CA certificate with DN 'OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US' that signed certificate with DN 'CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US'
```

I got an SSL certificate by accessing their web site and exporting the certificate by means of a web browser.  Question is, is there any other way to get a trusted certificate or should I need to contact the web site administrator to get one?

Thanks.

Comment: Importing the certificate into the browser will not work in most cases, Java does not access the OS certificate registry (applets may behave different). Is this a Java UI or a backend (server) application?

Comment: The exception is from a Java middleware application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear on what you are doing, but if you are using Java to call a web service through ssl, you will have to add that certificate to your jvm's keystore.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security6.html